# JSON Store change method with replaceCriteria MobileFirst 6.3

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

i have used JSON store change method with replaceCriteria

```
var changeOptions = {
              replaceCriteria : ['chartName','periode','office_id','parent_office_id'],
              addNew : true,
              markDirty : false //data came from the server
        };

WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).change(data, changeOptions);
```

my input data :

```
[{  chartName:"disiplin",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-06",
   value:100,
   title:"tes"
},
{  chartName:"portofolio",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-06",
   value:90,
   title:"tes2"
}]
```

my new data :

```
[{  chartName:"disiplin",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-07",
   value:100,
   title:"tes3"
},
{  chartName:"portofolio",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-07",
   value:90,
   title:"tes4"
}]
```

my changed data on windows phone :

```
[{
    id:4,
    json:{  
   chartName:"portofolio",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-07",
   value:90,
   title:"tes4"
  }
}]
```

Expected data (Android, iOS, BB10) :

```
[{ 
   id:1,
   json:{ 
   chartName:"disiplin",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-06",
   value:100,
   title:"tes"
   }
},
{  
   id:2,
   json:{
   chartName:"portofolio",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-06",
   value:90,
   title:"tes2"
   }
},
{  
   id:3,
   json:{
   chartName:"disiplin",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-07",
   value:100,
   title:"tes3"
   }
},
{  
   id:4,
   json:{
   chartName:"portofolio",
   parent_office_id:"1",
   office_id:"HO",
   periode:"2014-12-07",
   value:90,
   title:"tes4"
   }
}]
```

The code above is working fine on Android, iOS, and BB10. But when i tried on my Windows Phone 8 app, my new data always overwrite the data before. I think replaceCriteria is not working on windows phone 8. Is it true ?

Comment: Could you provide more of your code like your starting input data, your changed data, and the data that you expect?

Comment: @Namfo : i have added the data on my description

Answer (score 1):

Replace criteria is working correctly but the behavior on Windows is different than in Android/iOS/Blackberry.

In Windows the replace criteria uses OR operations rather than AND operations. So as long as it can find any of the search fields with the same values in your store it will replace it.

If you wish to change this use fewer replaceCriteria. You can also ask for a feature request.